# how to capture the retention bytes values from zookeeper meta data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we are trying to capture the `retention bytes` values from the topic - `topic_test`

we try the following example , but seems this isnt the right path from zookeeper

```
zookeeper-shell kafka1:2181,kafka2:2181,kafka3:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/topics/topic_test/partitions/88/state"
Connecting to kafka1:2181,kafka2:2181,kafka3:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[]
```

any  idea where are the values of `retention byte`s per topic that can capture from zookeeper?

**I did the following , but not see the retention bytes ( what is wrong here )** , we have kafka confluent `version - 0.1`

```
zookeeper-shell confluent1:2181 get /config/topics/test_topic
Connecting to kafka1:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
{"version":1,"config":{}}
cZxid = 0xb30a00000038
ctime = Mon Jun 29 11:42:30 GMT 2020
mZxid = 0xb30a00000038
mtime = Mon Jun 29 11:42:30 GMT 2020
pZxid = 0xb30a00000038
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 25
numChildren = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configurations are stored in Zookeeper under the `/config` path.

For example, for the topic `topic_test`:

```sh
# Create topic
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create \
    --topic topic_test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config retention.bytes=12345

# Retrieve configs from Zookeeper
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost get /config/topics/topic_test
Connecting to localhost

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
{"version":1,"config":{"retention.bytes":"12345"}}
```

---

Note in most cases, you should not rely on direct access to Zookeeper but instead use the Kafka API to retrieve these values.

Using:

- `kafka-topics.sh`:

  ```
  ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic topic_test
  ```
- `kafka-configs.sh`:

  ```
  ./bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --entity-type topics --entity-name topic_test
  ```
- The Admin API using [`describeConfigs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: please see my update in question - very strange that I not see the retention bytes

Comment: You will only see `retention.bytes` in Zookeeper if you've set that config on the topic when creating it. If you are using the broker default, configs do not appear. Use the Admin API of `kafka-configs.sh` if you want to retrieve that value in all cases

Comment: another quastion please - after we set the retention bytes , by the (/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create \
    --topic topic_test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config retention.bytes=12345) , and then we do reboot to the machine , after reboot retention bytes not apears from zookeeper , is it possible to save it , so after reboot it will also remained ?

Comment: Sorry it seems like a different issue altogether. Please post another question with all the details.

Comment: this is the new post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63041978/how-to-remaine-the-kafka-retentions-bytes-and-kafka-retention-segment-after-kafk

Comment: let me know if you need more details , since this post is very important to us -:)