# how to remaine the kafka retentions-bytes and kafka retention-segment even after kafka machine reboot

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we set `retention bytes` value - `104857600` for topic - `topic_test`

```
[root@confluent01 ~]# kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic  topic_test --config retention.bytes=104857600
WARNING: Altering topic configuration from this script has been deprecated and may be removed in future releases.
         Going forward, please use kafka-configs.sh for this functionality
Updated config for topic "topic_test".
```

Now we verify the `retention bytes` from the zookeeper:

```
[root@confluent01 ~]#  zookeeper-shell confluent01:2181 get /config/topics/topic_test
Connecting to confluent1:2181
{"version":1,"config":{"retention.bytes":"104857600"}}
cZxid = 0xb30a00000038

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
ctime = Mon Jun 29 11:42:30 GMT 2020
mZxid = 0xb31100008978
mtime = Wed Jul 22 19:22:20 GMT 2020
pZxid = 0xb30a00000038
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 7
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 54
numChildren = 0
```

now we performed `reboot` to the kafka confluent01  machine

after machines started and kafka service start successfully , we checked again the `retention-bytes` from zookeeper:

but now ( after machine reboot ) we can see that the `retention bytes` isn't configured in zookeeper

```
[root@confluent01 ~]#zookeeper-shell confluent01:2181 get /config/topics/topic_test
Connecting to confluent1:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null  no retention bytes value 

{"version":1,"config":{}}
cZxid = 0xb30a00000038
ctime = Mon Jun 29 11:42:30 GMT 2020
mZxid = 0xb3110000779b
mtime = Wed Jul 22 14:09:19 GMT 2020
pZxid = 0xb30a00000038
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 2
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 25
numChildren = 0
```

**the question is** - how to remain the `retention bytes` even after restart of kafka machine ?

***NOTE - we not want to use the retention bytes from `server.properties`
because we set different retention bytes to each topic***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zookeeper and Kafka default to store data in /tmp

If you reboot the machines, /tmp is cleared

Otherwise, if you use `confluent start` command, this is not permanent data.

If you use Docker/Kubernetes without mounting any volumes, this is also not permanent.

---

You sould also be using `kafka-topics --describe` command rather than `zookeeper-shell` as Zookeeper will be removed completely in upcoming Kafka releases

Comment: what you mean store the data under /tmo , on kafka machine unde r/tmp we not have nothing that related to kafka

Comment: for example I see al zookeeper data is under - /opt/confluent/etc/zookeeper/data/version-2

Comment: Kafka: `logs.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs`, Zookeeper `dataDir=/tmp`... These are the defaults

Comment: about - zookeeper-shell confluent01:2181 get /config/topics/topic_test
Connecting to confluent1:2181 , we are using it in order to verify the new retention bytes conf

Comment: And you should use `kafka-topics`, like I mentioned.

Comment: in kafka , the configuration file is - server.properties and in this file we see - log.dirs=/var/log/kafka , so its not under /tmp , and the quastion is why retention bytes deleted from zookeeper after machine reboot

Comment: do you mean to use - kafka-topics because zookeeper-shell  is deprecated  ?

Comment: No. Zookeeper-shell is not deprecated. It is part of Zookeeper, and cannot be deprecated. Kafka will no longer need Zookeeper one day (soon), so that Shell script will not be packaged with Kafka, and shouldn't be relied upon for your future use cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218409/discussion-between-jessica-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: ok so the suggestion is to use kafka-topics to verify the retention byes - just approve this ?  , second - still not get answer about how to avoid loosing of retention bytes configuration after machine reboot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218463/discussion-between-jessica-and-onecricketeer).